# Use Form variables in other subs

Tags: vb.net

I have an array of a class in a mybase.load and I want to use it in lots of other subs.
The mybase.load and the button click are both public subs i've used dims. Its probs a beginner question.

Cheers

```
   Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim Contracts() As Contract
    ReDim Contracts(CC)
    For c = 0 To CC
        Contracts(c) = New Contract
    Next
```

Hoe can I apply the module scope?

Comment: save it as a private module/class/form level variable; study http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx

Comment: okay so the module scope will do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form Load and Button events do not need to be Public, and probably should not be.  But they do not have anything to do with variable `Scope`.

```
Public Class frmMyForm

     ' declared outside a SUB/Function, these have
     ' module level scope
     Private myFoo As Integer
     Private myBar As String

     Private Sub frmMyForm_Load(...
         ' some code to do some stuff
         myFoo = 1
         myBar = "ziggy"

     End Sub

    Private Sub btnToDoSomething(....
         If myFoo <> 1 Then Exit Sub

         ' other code
    End Sub
End Class
```

Such variables can also be initialized in the constructor (`Sub New`) in cases where the form needs to have these values at the time it is instanced, or if the form should not exist without them.